# Does precedence of logical operators matter in libreoffice calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have the following query in libreoffice calc:

Extract records where grade is 1 or 2 and salary >= 10000 and salary <=20000

I used standard filters in the sequence grade = 1 or grade=2 and sal >= 10000 and sal<=20000

Using the above sequence, I am not getting the correct result

However, if I use the sequence as sal >= 10000 and sal<=20000 and grade = 1 or grade=2, then I am getting the correct result.

Is this due to Order of precedence?

Why I am getting different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it has to do with order.

In the first case, Calc tries to take records that meet the condition

`grade = 1 or (grade=2 and sal >= 10000 and sal<=20000)`

(All records for `grade = 1` and additionally records for `grade = 2` with `sal between 10000 and 20000`)

And in the second case, this condition

`sal >= 10000 and sal<=20000 and (grade = 1 or grade=2)`

That is exactly what you wanted to get.

You can read more details, for example, in [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

[image: Wiki_About_Order_of_operations]